# How to prevent data overloading (Inserting) in an API JSON URL?

Tags: json, api, jwt, overloading, symfony4

I've an API (Symfony + JWT) everything works well, but i'm wondring if one day someone for exemple had the link to register an user since the url is in public, how could i prevent data overloading in this case ?

To make it more clear because my english is weak :(

I've this link (1) : www.mysite.com/api/user/register (backend/JSON Post)

in another hand (2) : www.mysite.com/register (frontend)

if someone had the first link nd he dicided to ruin my database by a script that allows him to insert a lot of registrations !

Comment: institute a rate limiter that will blacklist an IP after so many hits within a time period

Comment: could you just give more details !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common practice is to do some kind of test (called ["captcha"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)) that verifies that the information that is sent to your API is produced by a human, not by a script or bot, and send the result of this test along with your registration form data.

There are even free APIs that you can use if you don't want to support your own logic for this like [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).

Comment: In fact i'm not talking about how to protect the frontend part, i'm talking about the api link !

Comment: I understand that. The API must deny registration data if it has no valid captcha token provided by the client along with it.